# How to generate a probability vector?

Tags: matlab, random, probability

I would like to generate a vector of probabilities that is following some known distribution.

For example when I want the distribution to be uniform I can do in MATLAB:

```
N     = 5;
proba = (1/(N))*ones(1, N);
```

What to do if I want to do it with Poisson distribution or Binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a solution that uses built-in MATLAB functions, you can look into [`random`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/random.html), which allows you to supply parameters to many types of well-known distributions.

For example, if you want to draw a `M x N` matrix of values from a binomial distribution with `n` trials and a `p` chance of success:

```
n=3; p=0.5; M=20; N=1;
random('Binomial',n,p,[M,N])
```

If you have a (discrete) probability distribution of your own creation, with the PMF given as a vector, you can sample from it by generating a random number `r` from a uniform distribution on `[0,1]` using `r=rand()` and then picking the first bin in the CMF which is greater than `r`.

```
x   = [  0   1   2   3  ];
PMF = [0.25 0.2 0.5 0.05];
CMF = cumsum(PMF);
N = 10000;
valuesDrawn = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
    r = rand();
    for j = 1:length(PMF)
        if r < CMF(j)
          valuesDrawn(i) = x(j);
          break;
        end
    end
end

hist(valuesDrawn);
```